# Using !{ } and #{ } interpolation in a jade template (exclamation-object, hash-object)

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

In a jade template (using express over node.js), I see a template using the following syntax:

```
script(type='text/template', id='data-services') !{data}
```

I don't understand the `!{ }` construct; apparently it interpolates a javascript object defined elsewhere as:

```
var data={ name:"Doe", age:"21" };
```

Jade docs & tuts show the use of `#{ }` for interpolation, but I don't see `!{ }`.  Even `#{ }` is not documented, so I think it's not jade-specific.  Where does this syntax come from and where is it documented?

Comment: Good question. Quite annoying that jade-lang.com doesn't even explain this!

Comment: It's in the pug documentation now: https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped

Answer (score 22):

Quite difficult to find it, indeed. Have a look at this resource:

http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#escaping

`#` is used when you want to escape data and `!` when you want it raw.

For example let's say that `name = "Hello <em>World</em>"`. Then you have:

```
#{name} --> Hello &lt;em&gt;World&lt;/em&gt;
!{name} --> Hello <em>World</em>
```

Think about it like that: `#` will display `name` as it is written while `!` will treat it as HTML.

Comment: thx freakish, thx naltatis for the missing docs. kind of funny jade forgot to explain interpolation...