# how do you pass html as a variable in to a jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am following an Isomorphic JavaScript example from this [repository](https://github.com/goatslacker/isomorphic-react-examples/tree/master/datetime) and the example renders html as a string to the jade template however I don't know if this is the best or only way to pass a html string in to a template

```
doctype html
html
  body
    #app!= html
  script(src="/public/js/bundle.js")
```

passing in the `html` variable from the server.js file

```
var html = Iso.render(React.renderToString(node), { altStores: data }, { react: true })

res.render('layout', { html: html })
```

Does this seem correct or is there a better way to do this in Jade? I have only started with jade and can't seem to find this in the API.

Comment: yeah, seems correct. Are you encountering any errors?

Comment: I don't have any errors, it does work. I just want to know if this is the correct way, as I don't see any documentation on the jade website on how to do this. I am also looking to pass other variables in so wanted to confirm it was the best way

Comment: There are other ways too. `res.locals.html = html` would do the same. `app.locals.html=html` too, but for all requests. Search for `locals` in the [docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html)

Comment: There's also the difference between [# and ! in Jade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557663/using-and-interpolation-in-a-jade-template-exclamation-object-hash-o)

Comment: okay thanks for your help, if you want to answer with those comments, and the most appropriate way to pass in the variable I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks