# how to pass script src in to jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a jade template that I want to pass in a variable as the script src, as on different routes the scripts will change. How can I do this in Jade and Express?

```
doctype html
html
  body
    #app!= html

  script(src={bundle})
```

passing in the `bundle` variable which I want in the script src

```
var html = React.renderToString(node)
var bundle = '/public/js/bundle.js'

res.render('layout', { html: html, bundle: bundle })
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I can answer this myself, after some help from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557663/using-and-interpolation-in-a-jade-template-exclamation-object-hash-o)

As it states `#` is used when you want to escape data and `!` when you want it raw.

```
doctype html
html
  body
    #app!= html

  script(src='#{bundle}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `#`, `!` and quotes. This works fine for me:

```
  doctype html
  block vars
    - var html = React.renderToString(node)
    - var bundle = '/public/js/bundle.js'
  html
    body
      #app!= html

      script(src=bundle)
```