# When to use string interpolation, unescaped !{} in pug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Is there a use case for !{} - string interpolation, unescaped? Given that it is risky to use?

I have checked the following links:

https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped

[Using !{ } and #{ } interpolation in a jade template (exclamation-object, hash-object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557663/using-and-interpolation-in-a-jade-template-exclamation-object-hash-o)

https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/8kcz7s/can_someone_explain_the_difference_between/

Answer (score 1):

Simply put from the doc : `never trust user input`
so answering your question
use `!{}` only when it's user input or some code you don't trust